# Vaadin Undertow - java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to store the icon image into the stream provided

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow, undertow, vaadin24

I use Vaadin Flow with Undertow and Spring Boot.

From time to time in the logs I see the following error:

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to store the icon image into the stream provided
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.PwaIcon.write(PwaIcon.java:240) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PwaHandler.lambda$init$1bc33a08$1(PwaHandler.java:83) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PwaHandler.handleRequest(PwaHandler.java:153) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1529) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:398) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:258) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:193) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:186) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:136) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:99) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:172) ~[undertow-websockets-jsr-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:217) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:563) ~[na:na]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:162) ~[xnio-nio-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:652) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:166) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:128) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:220) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:158) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:179) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2170) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeBlocking(Channels.java:202) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeTooLargeForBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:200) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:148) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.PwaIcon.write(PwaIcon.java:238) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    ... 81 common frames omitted

2023-05-16T11:40:27.170+03:00 ERROR 4109095 --- [XNIO-1 task-3] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /icons/icon-180x180.png

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to store the icon image into the stream provided
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:400) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:258) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:193) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:186) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:136) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:99) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:172) ~[undertow-websockets-jsr-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to store the icon image into the stream provided
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1578) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1541) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:398) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to store the icon image into the stream provided
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.PwaIcon.write(PwaIcon.java:240) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PwaHandler.lambda$init$1bc33a08$1(PwaHandler.java:83) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PwaHandler.handleRequest(PwaHandler.java:153) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1529) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:217) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:563) ~[na:na]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.write(NioSocketConduit.java:162) ~[xnio-nio-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:652) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.doWrite(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:166) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:128) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.write(ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.java:220) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:158) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:179) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2170) ~[undertow-core-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeBlocking(Channels.java:202) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeTooLargeForBuffer(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:200) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:148) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.5.Final.jar!/:2.3.5.Final]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.PwaIcon.write(PwaIcon.java:238) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha6.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha6]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

Is there something I can do to prevent it? Right now, I don't even know where to begin in order to fix it. Please help